# FAQ container not revealing on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, accordion, css-modules

[image: Console logs]
I am working a gatsby project. I am trying to make an FAQ where the when you click on the question it slides down the answer revealing it. However, for some reason the answer is always hidden despite the container console logging that its clicked.

here is the javascript:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'
import * as styles from './style-modules/faq.module.css'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';


const Faq = () => {
  const [faqs, setFaqs] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      console.log("Fetching data...")
      try {
        const result = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/faq")
        console.log("Data fetched successfully:", result.data)
        setFaqs(result.data)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error)
      }
    }

    fetchData()

}, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      const faqButtons = document.querySelectorAll(`.${styles.questions}`)
      console.log(faqButtons)

      const answersContainers = document.querySelectorAll(`.${styles.answers}`);

      faqButtons.forEach((faqButton, index) => {
        const answersContainer = answersContainers[index];

        const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(answersContainer);
        const maxHeight = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('max-height');
        console.log(maxHeight);

        if (faqButton == null || faqButton < 0) {
          console.log("No content in container")
        } else {
          console.log("Selecting Container...")
          faqButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            console.log("Container was clicked!")
            answersContainer.classList.toggle("open");
            console.log("Container was open!")
            console.log(maxHeight)
          });
        }
      });
    }, [faqs]);

    return (
      <Container>
        {faqs?.map(faq => (
          <div key={faq.questions} className={styles.faq}>
            <div className={styles.questions} >
              <h4>{faq.questions}</h4>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.answers}>
              <p>{faq.answers}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </Container>
    );
};

export default Faq;
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.faq_section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
}


.faq {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.questions {
    /* font-size: 5vmin; */
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(184, 184, 184)
}

.questions.active {
    background-color: rgb(207, 233, 237);
}

.questions:hover {
    background-color: rgb(207, 233, 237);
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in;
}

.answers {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

  .answer.open {
    height: 1000px;
  }
```

I tried added console logs to the code to pinpoint the issue. It seems the container is being clicked on, but for some reason the click is not switching the .open css style instead the max-height remains 0 which is why the answer container is being selected. As a learning experience my last resort would be to switch to the bootstrap components, but don't want to do that for now.

Comment: I can see at least 2 things that I think are bugs.  First, you don't ever seem to be setting the `answer` CSS class on any elements, so it makes sense that `.answer.open` wouldn't be selecting any elements.  Second, `height: 1000px` is probably not going to override `max-height: 0`.  Based on the presence of your `transition` property, I will hazard a guess and say that you might have meant to say `.answers.open{ max-height: 1000px; }` for your last selector?    If this comment doesn't answer your question, providing a codepen that demonstrates the problem will likely be helpful.

Comment: When using React, try to avoid using DOM manipulation. React won't play nice with it. Look at [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-wing-10zl47?file=/src/Accordion.js) on how to make an animatable accordion component.